# What is behind python package namespaces: z3c, zc, collective?

Tags: python, zope

So they all are somehow related to zope. Question is how?

I am not familiar with Zope. I guess that zc, z3c stand for `Zope Component` and `Zope3 Component` but I want to be sure. Also there is a `collective` namespace. What kind of packages goes under it?

What are other well known python package namespaces?

Are there any conventions when package should be namespaced with zc, z3c and others?

Sometimes I see packages starting with zc and I can't rationate why are they namespaced. For example `z3c.sqlalchemy` has namespace because it is a wrapper of `sqlalchemy` for zope projects. But another example `zc.buildout` looks like a completely independent project. Did it got the namespace only because it is developed by people who work on Zope? If I would work on Zope would that mean that I should prefix my projects with `zc` even if they are not relevant to any other Zope package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `zc` is "Zope Corporation".
- `z3c` is "Zope 3 community", a namespace that long since has been "deprecated", ie no new packages are made with this namespace.
- `collective` refers to the Plone Collective, a svn repository for Plone packages with a friendly attitude towards contributors. It's been the "default" namespace for new generic Plone packages that are not a part of Plone core for quite some time now.

Also of interest is:

- `zope` originally used for packages that was a part of Zope 3. Now rarely used for new packages.
- `Products`, used for older Zope2 / Plone packages. A hystorical remnant of the fact that all Zope2 products had to be in a Products directory, since before there was namespace packages.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan Richter and I where prototyping some packages on a zope sprint which didn't really fit into the zope package namespace. This was the time we started using z3c as a package name.
This should mean zope 3 community as Lennart says. But the namespace is not deprecated.

Probably the question is more which license commiter agreement does someone like to use if
he likes to commit to a zope package repository. I think z3c and collective use different license stuff.

The z3c repos is a part of the zope repository and uses the same license (ZPL) etc. as zope itself uses. But this also means you need to be a zope contributer for using it.

btw,
using the z3c or collective outside the relevant repositories is probably a very bad ide.

Regards
Roger Ineichen